# Is there a way to change logic apps default timezone?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Currently I'm using logic apps to get/send emails. However, I noticed that, the received/sending time in logic apps is by default in UTC time zone.
Since I'm sending and receiving a lot of emails in logic apps, It's tedious to convert it for each actions.
Is there a way to change the default UTC time zone to a different time zone so that it can reflect to all my logic apps functionality?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recurrence trigger, you can add it there by defineing the timezone property under advanced scheduling. You can also add it to the work flow definition like this:
"timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm using "When email arrives" trigger for my logic apps.

Comment: Same issue with my logic app, @Viknesh - Have you got any solution for this, can we change the timezone with the trigger "When email arrives" ??